# Pentaho Transformation Error: Error inserting 'unknown' row in dimension

Tags: postgresql, pentaho

[image]

Have a relatively simple transformation where I am selecting data from source, performing lookup and inserting into target. Source and Target are both Postgresql tables.

Both the source and target have the same table structure. And there are no NOT NULL columns in my source but still I get this error.

[image]

Source columns : Sku_id, cient_id, sku_number, display_order, title, detail, image, net_cost, total_cost, price, created_date, updated_date.

Target columns : sku_key, cient_id, sku_number, display_order, title, detail, image, net_cost, total_cost, price, effective_date, expiry_date, version.

[image]

Can anyone please help me resolve the error. As I have no idea for the exact cause for it. Thanks.

Comment: Kettle complains a not-null constraint in your target table NOT your source table. Did you check that?

Comment: NO NULL values in target too. I did some manual inserts previously.

Comment: What about a primary key (which implies not null constraints)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was create for the table

```
 CREATE TABLE dim_item_sku ( item_sku_key bigint NOT NULL, client_id bigint NOT NULL, sku_number character varying(255) NOT NULL, display_order integer NOT NULL, title text, detail text, story text, intro text, image character varying(255), net_cost numeric(19,5), total_cost numeric(19,5), price numeric(19,5), effective_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), expiry_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),  version integer);
```

AS PDI tries to insert a default row (i.e. row 0) I've made changes to my create statement for the transformation to work. As the default values for the columns are not specified specified in the create statement.

```
CREATE TABLE dim_item_sku ( item_sku_key bigint DEFAULT nextval('dim_item_sku_key_seq'::regclass), client_id bigint, sku_number character varying(255), display_order integer, title text, image character varying(255), net_cost numeric(10,2), total_cost numeric(10,2), price numeric(10,2), effective_date timestamp without time zone, expiry_date timestamp without time zone, version integer);
```

We can also get the transformation to work by specifying the default values in the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE dim_item_sku ( item_sku_key bigint NOT NULL default 0, client_id bigint NOT NULL default 0, sku_number character varying(255) NOT NULL default '00', display_order integer NOT NULL default 0, title text, detail text, story text, intro text, image character varying(255), net_cost numeric(19,5), total_cost numeric(19,5), price numeric(19,5), effective_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), expiry_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), version integer);`
```

You replace the default values (0 in my example) with any number of your choice.